# Using .find to search a string inside a list

Tags: python, string, list

I want to loop through a list of strings...

eg:

```
list_of_strings = ['Hello!, my name is Carl', 'Hello!, my name is Steve', 'Hello!, my name is Betty']
```

I want to loop through the list items and search for the location of 'Hello!' within the string in each case an record its location.

Any ideas?

Comment: post your attempts..

Comment: There's no need for that @Shashank, they have a well defined question, and just browsing documentation isn't going to help much.

Comment: @JoshSmeaton If you say so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to collect the indexes of your wanted string:

```
>>> list_of_strings = ['Hello!, my name is Carl', 'Hello!, my name is Steve', 'Hello!, my name is Betty', 'My Name is Josh']
>>> [s.find('Hello!') for s in list_of_strings]
[0, 0, 0, -1]
```

Note how the negative 1 shows that the final string does not contain the value you're looking for.

Comment: Again, what about encourages him learn to program, and the language, instead give answers?

Comment: The original poster already indicated that he knew about `.find()` but they weren't sure how to apply that to a list. As far as I'm concerned, that's enough to show me that they've attempted a solution. Providing an example is much more useful than pointing someone at the documentation for list comprehensions without showing how they can be used.

Comment: Exactly, if you provide just links then somebody will come along and say, 'oh hey links might change' so provide a working solution

Comment: Thanks @JoshSmeaton, this is exactly what I was after. I assumed you could use .find but couldn't get it to work on a string inside a list. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`string.find`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find) method.

```
>>> phrase = 'Hello, my name is Syko'
>>> phrase.find('Hello')
0
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

[(s, s.lower().index('hello')) for s in list_of_strings if s.lower() == 'hello']

Comment: What about encourages him learn to program, and the language, instead give answers?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> list_of_strings = ['Hello!, my name is Carl', 'Hello!, my name is Steve', 'Hello!, my name is Betty']

>>> indices = [position for position, phrase in enumerate(list_of_strings) if 'Hello!' in phrase]
>>> print indices
[0, 1, 2]
```

Using a comprehension list, loop over the list and check if the string has the `Hello!` string inside, if yes, append the `position` to the matches list.

Note: The `enumerate` build in brings you the index for each element in the list.

Comment: He is a beginner. He even don't know a loop, imagine an enumerate!

Comment: Ok, @syko, everyone here trust in you. Take it like a challenge and just do it. I think this online book is a good starting point: http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/index.html

Comment: Thanks @sgmart. enumerate's look cool. I'll read up some more.

Answer (score 1):

in case you are searching for multiple items in a list say Hello and name

`find = lambda searchList, elem: [[i for i, x in enumerate(searchList) if x == e] for e in elem]
find(list_of_strings,['Hello','name'])`

output is a list with the positions of the elements you are searching for in the order that you listed them

Comment: Thanks for this, really useful actually. I already broke the string with another process, but this could have helped me avoid the need :-)